# chomp in perl not working as expected

Tags: perl, chomp

I found a strange behavior of chomp in Perl and I am unable to comprehend why is chomp is working like this.

The following line does not work as expected

```
if ( chomp($str1) eq chomp($str2) )
```

But, the following works fine

```
chomp $str1;
chomp $str2;
if ( $str1 eq $str2 )
```

Can you please give some insight in this behavior of chomp?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`chomp` modifies its argument. It does not return a modified argument. The second example is, in fact, how you're supposed to use it.

***edit***: `perldoc -f chomp` says:

```
   chomp   This safer version of "chop" removes any trailing string that
           corresponds to the current value of $/ (also known as
           $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR in the "English" module).  It returns
           the total number of characters removed from all its arguments.
```

Comment: +1. To be more explicit: `chomp` takes one or more arguments, modifies them if necessary, and "returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments". [[link](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)]

Comment: I have always thought that there should be an `rchomp` which behaves as the OP expected. I think that `chomp( my $input = <> );` looks really awkward, wouldn't you rather `my $input = rchomp <>`

Comment: I hate these C-style interfaces that modify arguments. [Text::Chomped](http://p3rl.org/Text::Chomped) is the work-around.

Comment: The original idea behind modifying it in place is that you can write your perl script with implicit arguments (`$_`) and have it all like `while(<STDIN>) { chomp; next if /begin_pattern/../end_pattern/; s/x/y/; print; }` -- that's where Perl comes from, historically, and that's the source of most of the things people find quirky. I agree that it's dubious in most modern programming, though.

Answer (score 2):

`chomp` returns the number of characters removed, not the strings that have been chomped.

Answer (score 2):

I like the name chomp() it's sound tells you what it does. As @ruakh mentions it takes one or more arguments, so you can say:

```
chomp($str1,$str2);
if ( $str1 eq $str2 ) ...
```

You can also hand it an array of strings, like what you would get from reading a whole file at once, e.g.:

```
chomp(@lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use `s,$/$,,r` regex as a non-destructive chomp. It removes record separator `$/` from the end of `$_` or the string provided using `=~`, and returns the result without modifying anything. Your example would look like this:

```
if ( $str1 =~ s,$/$,,r eq $str2 =~ s,$/$,,r )
```

More formally the regex should be `s,\Q$/\E$,,r`, so `$/` is not treated as regex. In paragraph mode the regex would need to be `s,\n*$,,r`. In slurp or fixed record mode the regex is not needed at all (chomp does nothing).